# log4j.properties Ignored when running sbt test

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j, sbt

I am working on a Spark application in Scala which utilizes SBT for its builds.  Spark creates very verbose logging which I would like to ignore when tests are running.

I have a log4j.properties file set up under src/test/resources, as well as src/main/resources with the following content:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{10}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.akka=ERROR
log4j.logger.Remoting=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=ERROR
```

When running the application with `sbt test` or running a full application, it runs correctly but still logs all of the INFO level statements which are relevant for Spark

Is there something I'm missing in the file configuration, or do I need to explicitly tell sbt to load log4j.properties?  Should I try a new approach all together?

I am also restricted in that the application needs to be able to run on our CI environment and other users computers with the logging settings applied.  This means that the settings need to be included and recognized from the application's git repo.

Comment: Have you eventually solved the problem? ('cause I'm in the same situation)

Comment: Are  the unit tests connecting to spark that is *started by the unit test* or to a spark server that has a different lifecycle from the unit test - ie. is already running and continues to run after the tests are completed?

Comment: @daveoncode My answer got downvoted but it was  a working solution already 6 years ago. I keep it there for a reference for myself in any case .

Answer (score -3):

Please copy your log4j.properties to the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` directory.  That is the one used by the spark installation

Comment: The settings need to be stored and used local to the application directory itself so they can be shared between other users and our CI environment.  Forcing specific global logging settings for Spark is not an option

Comment: This is what is needed to resolve the issue. There are options to handle this such as a post-install script or action to copy the [`log4j.[xml|properties`] on each machine.  Noone came back with an alternative - including you